# Ordenar en python según 3 listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tengo 3 listas RUT,CARRERA, DEUDA, lo cual me piden ordenar que los rut que son iguales y tienen la misma carrera debo sumar la deuda, si el rut tiene diferente carrera entonces se mantiene como diferentes y serian 2 deudas asociada a estas.
Soy nuevo en esto y no se me ocurre otra manera mas facil pero me tira error. Tambien se permite ordenamiento por matrices u otro metodo pero de principiante.

Este programa me tira error

> ```
> File "C:/Users/sistem/Desktop/ython/deudas.py", line 65, in <module>
> ordenar(rut,carrera,deuda,ruts,carreras,deudas)
> File "C:/Users/sistem/Desktop/ython/deudas.py", line 22, in ordenar
> deuda1=float(deuda[i])+float(deuda[i+1])
> IndexError: list index out of range
> ```

```
def ordenar(rut,carrera,deuda,ruts,carreras,deudas):
     i=1
     j=1
     for rut[i] in rut:
         if deuda[j] in deuda:
             deuda1=float(deuda[i])+float(deuda[i+1])
             deudas.append(deuda1)
             ruts.append(rut[i])
             carreras.append(carrera[i])
             j=j+1

         else:
             deudas.append(deuda[i])
             ruts.append(rut[i])
             carreras.append(carrera[i])
         i=i+1

     return
```

Comment: iría bien proporcionar un [mcve] para poder "jugar" con los datos.

Comment: Como dice Fedorqui deberias aportar algo de datos extra. No es necesario más código, simplemente un ejemplo real de las tres listas y como deberian quedar tras 'ordenar' sería de gran ayuda para poder reproducir fácilmente el problema y ver otros detalles como el tipo de datos. Realmente lo que pareces querer es agrupar y no ordenar. El error se debe a `deuda[i+1]` cuando i es el último indice de la lista `deuda`, pero tienes otros problemas con el algoritmos si quieres hacer lo que creo (por ejemplo, `if deuda[j] in deuda:` no tiene sentido, siempre va a ser `True`. ).

Comment: Por otro lado, lo que pretendes hacer puede ser muy simple o más engorroso dependiendo de que te dejen usar. Usar bibliotecas externas como Pandas solo requiere una linea para hacer la agrupación, esto lo descarto. No obstante, si te dejan usar la biblioteca estándar de Python  `itertools.Groupby` puede simplificar mucho las cosas. Para no dar respuestas que no te van a servir, aclarar que puedes y que no puedes usar es de gran ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: ¿Por qué se incluyen etiquetas de dos versiones de Python?